# 'skip-backup' attribute always returns backup instead of skip process

Tags: backup

i use this method for do not backup and that output is always success . but backup data also come in backup in ipad please help me.

```
-(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) {
    // iOS 5.0.1 and lower
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
else
{
    // First try and remove the extended attribute if it is present
    int result = getxattr(filePath, attrName, NULL, sizeof(u_int8_t), 0, 0);
    if (result != -1) {
        // The attribute exists, we need to remove it
        int removeResult = removexattr(filePath, attrName, 0);
        if (removeResult == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Removed extended attribute on file %@", URL);
        }
    }
    // Set the new key
    NSError *error = nil;
    [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
    return error == nil;
}
}
```

above method i use .please help me anybody.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve that problem .i found bug for `NSUserdefault` this `NSUserdefault` stored data store in preference in `plist` file so that `NSUserdefault` data remove and solve problem.